# Intellisense types unavailable with CommonJS + node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellisense

### Issue

Using the popular [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library, Intellisense doesn't understand the return value of `fetch()`.

Vim with coc:

[image: inspecting the return type of fetch, I see const result: any]

Same thing in VSCode:

[image: same thing in VSCode]

For most other libraries I have type completion, but this one does not work.

### Things I tried

1. Added `jsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.json` files
2. Investigated the package, which exports a `@types/index.d.ts`
3. Tried installing `@types/node-fetch`, which also falls out-of-date often
4. Converted to `import` syntax, which works

### Expected result

As I mentioned, changing to `import` syntax fixes the issue, but I want it to work with `require` too.

[image]

How can I have type completion on this library with CommonJS?

Comment: Had the same problem as you OP. I ended up using `axios` instead and it seems to work much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch').default
```

---

### Explanation

To bridge fundamental differences between CommonJS and ES module syntax, `require('node-fetch')` returns an object with this shape:

[image: node REPL showing the result of node-fetch as an object with a property called default]

Notice the [node-fetch type definition](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/d8fc32d6b29bd43d1ad377e80b3e439fe37f2904/%40types/index.d.ts#L176) *does* export the `fetch()` function as the top level, but also exports a `default` property for compatibility with ES module syntax. Using this property fixes autocomplete issues.

[image]

This still seems like a bug to me, but this workaround does resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

This works no problem, have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I do not have concern with the functionality of node-fetch, only the type information and auto-completion via intellisense. I updated my post to include a screenshot of the expected result.

Comment: I see no issue, const result with type of any, and the result error is you haven't used the variable yet.

Comment: The result should be type `Promise<Response>`

Comment: To sum that one, difference comes down to how require and import work.

Comment: Why does it work with some libraries and not others? For example [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) works fine

Comment: Generally how they're written, they're done by folks like you or I, anyone who wants to contribute to the cause.  You could approach their github. :)

Comment: Yes I have written many .d.ts files and typescript files, but I feel confused about the breakage here. I can ask github but I figured the problem was PEBCAK.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import node_fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fetch = node_fetch.default;

fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

(See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Mind you, I think there must be a better way to get the default import...

Comment: My question specifically concerns autocomplete with CommonJS in node. Your suggestion causes this error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: I understand. I have edited the answer after trying the code myself. What I have above is the typescript way to import a commonJs module. Something odd is happening if you have that error, since typescript should treat anything with a top-level import as a module. Documentation suggests adding `export {}` to the top of the file to force it to be treated as a module, though with the import it should not be required. Maybe you haven't got the import at the top level in your actual code?

Comment: Reading this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2719 it seems there may not be a cleaner way than this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion "I think there must be a better way to get the default import" hit the nail on the head.